# Checking if $\det[\epsilon \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}] - \epsilon^n$ is a monotonic function

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-calculus, trace, monotone-functions

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $n \times n$ positive semi-definite matrix, and let $\epsilon$ be a non-negative real  number. I am interested in if the following function increases if $\epsilon$ increases (i.e., the function is monotonic with respect to $\epsilon$):

$$f(\epsilon) = \det[\epsilon \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}] - \epsilon^n $$

To check this, I can take the derivative of $f$ with respect to $\epsilon$ and check if the derivative is positive. The derivative is the following (assuming I did not make a mistake):

$$\frac{df}{d\epsilon} = \det[\epsilon \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}] \text{tr}[(\epsilon \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A})^{-1}] - n\epsilon^{n-1}$$

However, I am having trouble showing this quantity is positive. I am fairly certain the quantity is positive based on some quick numerical experiments, but I want to verify analytically. Any thought on how to either show the first equation is monotonic or show the second equation is positive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are the (necessarily real, non-negative) eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ up to multiplicity, then
$$\det[\varepsilon \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{A}] - \varepsilon^n = (\lambda_1 + \varepsilon)\ldots(\lambda_n + \varepsilon) - \varepsilon^n.$$
Indeed, we can dispense with determinants and the matrices, and simply consider the function
$$f(\varepsilon) = (\lambda_1 + \varepsilon)\ldots(\lambda_n + \varepsilon) - \varepsilon^n$$
where $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ are arbitrary non-negative numbers. This is because we can form any positive-semidefinite $\mathbf{A}$ with these eigenvalues by simply placing them along the diagonal.

To prove $f$ is monotone, we can, as you tried, take the derivative. The derivative comes to, using the product rule,
\begin{align*}
f'(\varepsilon) &= \sum_{j=1}^n \prod_{\substack{1 \le i \le n \\ i \neq j}} (\lambda_i + \varepsilon) - n\varepsilon^{n-1} \\
&\ge \sum_{j=1}^n \prod_{\substack{1 \le i \le n \\ i \neq j}} \varepsilon - n\varepsilon^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \varepsilon^{n-1} - n\varepsilon^{n-1} \\
&= n\varepsilon^{n-1} - n\varepsilon^{n-1} = 0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $f$ is monotone increasing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$ be the characteristic polynomial. Then
$$ \det(\varepsilon I + A) = (-1)^n\det (-\varepsilon I - A) = (-1)^np(-\varepsilon) $$
This is a monic polynomial of degree $n$ whose roots are *minus* the eigenvalues of $A$. When $A$ is positive semidefinite this means that the $n$ roots are all nonpositive. Therefore, Descartes' rule of signs tells us that there cannot be any sign changes among its coefficients. So all the coefficients are nonnegative, and this continues to hold when we subtract the leading term $\varepsilon^n$ away.

However, a polynomial with no negative coefficients is non-decreasing for positive arguments.

(If $A=0$ you do get $f(\varepsilon)=0$ which is strictly speaking not increasing -- but that special case probably won't bother you in practice).

Comment: It's interesting. I almost forget  *Descartes' rule of signs*. However, if you know already that the $n$ roots are all non positive, there is no need to apply Descartes' rule of signs here.

Comment: @NN2: I'm using the rule of signs in the "reverse" direction, reasoning _from_ the known number and signs of the roots _to_ the signs of the coefficients.

Comment: Yes, but as you know already that the roots are *minus* the eigenvalues of $A$, you have directly that all the coefficients of $g(x) = \det (x I +A)$  are positive. And then the function $f(x) = g(x) -x^n$ having all positive coefficients is monotone for $\epsilon >0$

Comment: @NN2: Hmm, _why_ do I have that the coefficients are positive, if not by Descartes?

Comment: A function $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (a_i x + b_i)$ with $a_i,b_i \ge 0$ has coefficients that are all positive. It seems straightforward. But perhaps you want to prove that to make the proof more rigorous? $$$$ Another proof for that is to develop the function $f(x)$ and the coefficient of $x^k$ is $$\sum_{0 \le i \le k} a_i b_{k-i}$$ which is positive.

Comment: @NN2: Ah, you're saying to factor the polynomial into linear factors and then multiply out? Yes, that would work too.